# 529 Funds and Scholarship Refunds

Tags: united-states, 529-plan, education, refund, scholarship

I have a unique situation with my college billing:

For a handful of semesters at a local community college, I had to pay for my schooling (nothing special there), and I continued to do so like normal as the semesters continued. I paid for these semesters out of my 529 account.

But then I received a refund check in the mail for the amount paid from the 529 account.

My online statement read as follows (adjusted for conciseness and confidentiality but relevant info shown):
Semester 1
[image: Table of Account Activity]

I am wondering if that 'Refund of Acct Check' (exact words on statement) could be interpreted as a refund of the **Scholarship Check Payment** line, rather than a refund of the 529 monies.

**If that refund cannot be interpreted as the scholarship, rather that it IS $1,880 of 529 funds**, what action should be taken if the tax year those refunds occurred in has passed?

Edit: The 529 account itself is based in Indiana and the person who created the account and beneficiary are residents of the Commonwealth of Massachusetts. Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe the actual procedure will vary by state, but the general guidelines would no be state specific.  But to be safe, could you indicate the state?

Comment: I will edit the question with this information @mhoran_psprep: The 529 account itself is based in Indiana and the person who created the account and beneficiary are residents of the Commonwealth of Massachusetts. Hope this helps.

Comment: Who issued the scholarship? Did you apply for the scholarship? Did *you* receive that refund check?

Comment: The scholarship is actually a state grant program, not really a scholarship. You need to be a part of a particular program to receive it (currently a part of the program and was a part at the time of the ‘scholarship check’ being applied to the account). I received *a* refunded check, but not *the* scholarship check, if that makes sense. The scholarship check was applied to the college balance after all amounts owed were satisfied, and as a result a refund check was generated. I imagine it would be the same type of deal if I just sent in too much money from any source (they send it back).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you paid your tuition, and then the payment was refunded to you because you received a scholarship.

In order for this not to be a disqualified distribution from your 529 fund, you need to re-contribute it to 529 within 60 days of receipt (of the refund).

See the [IRS guidance here](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/irs-offers-guidance-on-recent-529-education-savings-plan-changes):

> The PATH Act change added a special rule for a beneficiary of a 529 plan, usually a student, who receives a refund of tuition or other qualified education expenses. This can occur when a student drops a class mid-semester. **If the beneficiary recontributes the refund to any of his or her 529 plans within 60 days, the refund is tax-free**.
>
> The Treasury Department and the IRS intend to issue future regulations simplifying the tax treatment of these transactions. Re-contributions would not count against the plan’s contribution limit.

Also: The [IRS Publication 970](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p970#en_US_2021_publink100042887).

Keep all the documentation, including proofs for the dates of refunds and recontributions, in case of an audit.

---

You mentioned in the comments that 60 days have passed. That makes it non-qualified distribution. There are still several points to remember:

- If you had additional [qualified expenses](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p970#en_US_2021_publink1000178566) that you paid out of your own pocket - you can allocate that money to them. That makes the allocated portion qualified.
- If the scholarship that you received is non-taxable - then the refunded 529 distribution, the non-qualified part of it, is taxable - but there would be no penalty. You only pay taxes on the earnings.

If you don't have any other qualified expenses and you don't qualify for the tax-free scholarship exception or any of the other exceptions listed in Pub. 970 - you're out of luck, you'll pay taxes on earnings *and* the 10% penalty.

See details on calculating the taxable portion in the [IRS Publication 970](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p970#en_US_2021_publink1000178534), especially the relevant [exceptions](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p970#en_US_2021_publink1000178566) section:

> The 10% additional tax doesn't apply to the following distributions.
>
> ...
>
> - Included in income because the designated beneficiary received:
>
>   - A tax-free scholarship or fellowship grant (see Tax-Free Scholarships and Fellowship Grants in chapter 1);
>   - Veterans' educational assistance (see Veterans' Benefits in chapter 1);
>   - Employer-provided educational assistance (see chapter 10); or
>   - Any other nontaxable (tax-free) payments (other than gifts or inheritances) received as educational assistance.
> - This exception only applies to the extent the distribution isn't more than the scholarship, allowance, or payment.
>
> ...

The taxable income goes on the line 8z of the [Schedule **1** for the Form 1040](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040s1.pdf). Use the [form 5329 part II](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-5329) to calculate the penalty, and add the result on line 8 of the [Schdule **2** for the Form 1040](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040s2.pdf).

Comment: So I imagine by your answer, that the refund would be considered a refund of the 529 funds, not the scholarship money?

Comment: Yes, since it was sent to you and not to whoever provided the scholarship

Comment: Okay. One other thing- as pointed out in the question, **what action should be taken if the tax year those refunds occurred in has passed?** For clarification, let's say greater than 180 days since the money was refunded.

Comment: @DisplayName added some more details for you